# how do i fix noisy brakes

Tags: brakes

My altima 2008 brakes squeal when touched lightly. I bought the Bosch BC815 QuietCast Brake Pad Set, hoping that "QuietCast" means that they are cast to be quiet, but they really don't. I'm now at the point where I would rather spend $$$ and buy a rotor/brake set that doesn't squeal. Anyone has any recommendations? Preferably if you got the same  problem

FYI: Brakes are NOT dysfunctional. They function perfectly, and I am aware that squealing is an indicator that they work fine. I just want to move squealing into a frequency that I do not hear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did not replace the hardware they may be the cause of the noise. It is fairly common for most brake pads to slide on a steel clip that slides over the caliper mounting bracket. The clips sometimes come with the pads and sometimes must be purchased separately. The clips provide a smooth surface for the pads to slide on. They also apply pressure to the pad to prevent vibration and noise. I like to apply a small dab of grease under the clip and in the slot that the pads ride in. I also apply some "disc brake quiet" to the back of the pads at the caliper contact points.

Comment: I reassembled the brakes applying grease to the clips, and also applied "disk brake quiet" while I was on it. Squeaking is gone

Answer (score 1):

Your brakes may just be dirty. Get a can of brake cleaner and follow the instructions. Also take the time to apply grease to moving parts (be careful not to get grease on the contact surfaces).